# App crash on MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nodemon

I've a mean stack application in which Im supplying db with some inputs including emails. Now in this case each email should be a unique entry and upon entering duplicate email the app fails which is expected.

The nodemon behind fails with message

`MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection`

and then throws another error

`[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...`

after which it fails to restart automatically. Manually when I restart the nodemon , everything works fine but need some process that nodemon should resume after showing the above message.

Is there's any way to achieve the same?

Here's some code for the same in my service running

```
updateClient(req, res){
    _db.Client.update( {code: req.body.code }, {  $set:{
       _db.Client.update( {code: req.body.code }, {  $set:{
  name:req.body.name,
      desc:req.body.desc,
      ...
      contract:{signedBy:req.body.contract.signedBy, start:req.body.contract.start, end:req.body.contract.end},
      ...
       }}).exec((err, docs) => {
           if (err || docs.ok !== 1) {
             log.error(err);
             res.send({ success: false, message: 'Meesage on fail' });
           }
           if (docs.ok === 1) {
             res.send({ success: true, message: 'message on fail' });
           }
       });
```

Error that I got

```
E11000 duplicate key error collection: hrms.clients index: contact.email_1 dup key: { : "asidansd@jsanod.com" }
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: hrms.clients index: contact.email_1 dup key: { : "asidansd@jsanod.com" }
    at Function.MongoError.create (/Users/***/hrms/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
    at toError (/Users/***/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:139:22)
    at /Users/***/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1059:67
    at /Users/***/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
```

Also my schema is defined as follows

```
static get Schema(){
    return mongoose => ({
        name: { type: String},
       ...
        contract:{signedBy:{type:String}, start:{type:Date}, end:{type:Date}},
```

...
        })
    }

Comment: @Dominic made an edit, the code pretty congested hence couldn't post all of it,

Comment: Are you sure there's no more error stack before the app crashes?

Comment: A duplicate key error has more detail than what you posted. It specifically shows which key the error is encountered on. I suggest showing the whole error, the content of `...myDataObject` in your failing request, along with the document in the collection you expect to update. Odds are you created a unique index on something you really should not have, and probably by misunderstanding what the unique index was for.

Comment: @NeilLunn have edited the code

Comment: `contact.email_1 dup key: { : "asidansd@jsanod.com" }`. It means you are trying to update a document with the same `contact.email` ( an embedded field ) content as you have an another document. I'm guessing `contact` is probably an array? Right? And you're probably using Mongoose ( the stack trace actually says you are ) and just marked that field as "unique" because you wanted "unique" items **within the array**. That's not what `"unique"` means there, but it's a common mistake.

Comment: @NeilLunn Ahh i see, so how do I resolve it, is using unique has to re-implemented , because that really Im looking for, each document should've a unique email here in my case

Comment: Well if you actually do mean **document**, then you resolve it by simply not providing the same duplicate data. But as for "app crashing", then your general question is still a bit "obtuse".

Comment: There is no *visible* reason in the code above that would cause the process to "crash". Possibly your `log` is actually doing a `throw` or something else. Instead of giving us "your whole code" ( or small interpreted part thereof ) instead read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and provide the **smallest possible and self contained** code **within your question** which actually reproduces the issue (AKA, a "unit test"). Then someone can actually point out what you did wrong and how to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Please Put your Schema in your Question.It is common if you schema's email_1 is unique.

```
  username: {
    unique: [true, "Username alraedy available"],
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Username is required"],
    }
  },
```